# Highcharts marker size change on/after hover

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

There is another problem with highcharts marker size. There are 3 properties, size depends on: radius, height, width. The default values of radius is 4. I`m setting height and width of marker, which depends on some data, for example:

```
 marker: {
     height: 50,
     width: 70,
     symbol: 'circle'
 }
```

The the graph is rendering. Here is, how it looks: [image]

But after, or on hover action size changes. It returns to the default value of RADIUS, and ignoring my values of height and width:
[image]

Any ideas, how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried setting the hover state manually to the same values? Not sure if this is correct, but you could try to set plotOptions.series.states.hover.marker.width/height as well.

Comment: @KjetilNordin no. There isn`t any reaction on this

Comment: I would take a look at the **point mouseOver** and **point mouseOut** events. Reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut

Comment: I think this is a bug that `width` and `height` changes anything. According to the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker.width) - width/height should be available for image markers only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work, by wrapping `setState` method in Highcharts (or using `mouseOver` event). Here is simple example:

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'setState', function (p) {
    p.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));

    if (this.marker && this.graphic) {
      this.graphic.attr({
        width: this.marker.width,
        height: this.marker.height
      });
    }
  });
})(Highcharts);
```

And live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o5nkeup7/1/

I suggest to disable `halo` - halo path is always circle, and won't work in your case.